# Symfony 3.3 autoconfigure services and usage

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I updated my project to Symfony 3.3. I want to use the new autoconfigure feature for services. I tried to get rid of `$this->get()` but I have errors in Controllers and Commands.

With the code sample below in a Controller, I have this error:

```
recapitulatifCollesAction() requires that you provide a value for the "$checkGele" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.
```

In commands, I don't know how to get rid of `$container->get()` at all.

Do you have an idea how I can get this to work ?

Controller:

```
public function recapitulatifCollesAction($estEnCours, CheckGeleService $checkGele)
{
    // ...
    $checkGele->getGeleAutorisation($colle);
    // ...
}
```

My config:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

Edit : new error after modifying config.yml

[image: New error message]

Answer (score 2):

For controllers you need also add the service argument resolver to autowire service in "actions" methods. This's all about default autowiring in 3.3:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Controller, Entity, Repository}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: [ controller.service_arguments ]
```

Comment: I have a 500 error when I had this to my config. It's really difficult to debug since I don't see anything in logs...

Comment: I have a new error message : `The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Resources\public\ckeditor\samples\old\assets\posteddata" to be defined in file "root\vendor\composer/../../src\AppBundle\Resources\public\ckeditor\samples\old\assets\posteddata.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in root\app/config\config.yml.`

I checked and this file is not even a class supposed to be loaded. It's a plain php file. So I excluded Resources folder from being imported in services but I still have the same error

Comment: And a weird thing happens : this file `posteddata.php` is loaded when I go to home page so I have it's content at the top of the Symfony error page (check updated first post)

Comment: It seems that your `Resources/public` folder contains some third-party lib PHP files (`posteddata.ph‌​p` here). You need to exclude them from the service autoconfiguration, by setting this `exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Controller, Entity, Repository, Resources}'` in the `AppBundle\:` entry.